# NAS storage in Docker Container

Tags: docker, storage, dockerfile, nas

I face a problem to implement the NAS on container in my datacenter. here is the scenario when the app( Container ) starts it needs to create the NAS folder on the host and should access the files from there. folders should be create in the run time. things i tried.

1. Using -v i have connected the server folder and container manually ( But this will fail when the container moved to other server )
2. --from option i can able to connect the one container files to others [ this also done manually] ( But is there any way when the container starts it can create a storage folder in the other container and access the files)  ?

Your guess/suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: are you using a swarm? Then have a look at the `docker stack deploy` and the labels, so the container deploys only on the host with the appropriate volume.

Comment: Alternatively you can look at `docker volume create` and check if you find an appropriate driver that mounts you NAS on all your other servers?

Comment: No i'm using  mesossphere. docker volume create can be perform by only entering manually

Comment: I then can only recommend to create volumes or mount your NAS on all servers when a server starts up/joins the cluster. I'm sure you can somehow put labels on servers, that prevents the start of a container on a host with a missing label.